# How can I count assosiations in sequelize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

i write this question because I faced with the next problem, I don't know how can i count amount of assosiations.

I have next models:

```
const Picture = sequelize.define<IPictureInstance>('picture', {
id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true },
img: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
mainTitle: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
description: { type: DataTypes.TEXT }});

const PictureTag = sequelize.define<IPictureTagInstance>('pictureTag', {
id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true },
text: { type: DataTypes.TEXT, allowNull: false }});

const PicturesTags = sequelize.define<IPicturesTagsInstance>('picturesTags', {
id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true }});
```

And their relations:

```
Picture.belongsToMany(PictureTag, { through: PicturesTags, as: "tags", onDelete: 'cascade' });
PictureTag.belongsToMany(Picture, { through: PicturesTags, as: "pictures", onDelete: 'cascade' });
```

The idea is to get a list of tags, which text property has a value, that at least partially contains a request text value.

For now I create the next method:

```
static async getTagsByText(tagText: string) {
if (!tagText) {
  return null;
}

if (!tagText.split(' ').join('')) {
  return null;
}

const processedTagText = tagText.split(' ').join('').toLowerCase();
const tags = await models.PictureTag.findAll(
  {
    where: { text: { [Op.regexp]: processedTagText } },
    include: "pictures",
  }
);

return tags;
```

}

Example of response of this method with argument "ba":

```
{
"id": 1,
"text": "barbarian",
"createdAt": "2022-03-26T07:50:39.421Z",
"updatedAt": "2022-03-26T07:50:39.421Z",
"pictures": [
    {
        "id": 13,
        "img": "58dab6f0-cf5c-42fe-afeb-063c92808d00.jpg",
        "mainTitle": "Berserk",
        "description": "Well, that's my first test",
        "createdAt": "2022-03-26T08:35:37.841Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-03-26T08:35:37.841Z",
        "userId": 1,
        "pictureTypeId": null,
        "picturesTags": {
            "id": 16,
            "createdAt": "2022-03-26T08:35:37.883Z",
            "updatedAt": "2022-03-26T08:35:37.883Z",
            "pictureId": 13,
            "pictureTagId": 1
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 15,
        "img": "4feab8f1-c8ce-433c-b38b-e88fc99d391f.jpg",
        "mainTitle": "MyCat",
        "description": "This is the photo of my cat",
        "createdAt": "2022-03-26T09:03:53.262Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-03-26T11:40:31.286Z",
        "userId": 1,
        "pictureTypeId": null,
        "picturesTags": {
            "id": 23,
            "createdAt": "2022-03-26T09:03:53.304Z",
            "updatedAt": "2022-03-26T09:03:53.304Z",
            "pictureId": 15,
            "pictureTagId": 1
        }
    }
  ]
}
```

For now it returns a list of pictures which are connected with this tag.
But I need to count amount of pictures, which are connected with this tag, how can I do this, would be grateful for the answer, thanks.

--------MY-SOLUTION------

For now I have the next solution:

```
static async getTagsByText(tagText: string) {
if (!tagText) {
  return null;
}

if (!tagText.split(' ').join('')) {
  return null;
}

const processedTagText = tagText.split(' ').join('').toLowerCase();
let tags = await models.PictureTag.findAll(
  {
    where: { text: { [Op.regexp]: processedTagText } },
    include: [{
      model: models.Picture,
      as: "pictures",
    }],
    attributes: ["id", "text"],
    limit: 5
  }
);

//process each tag in result array
tags = await Promise.all(tags.map((tag) => {
  const tagToEdit = tag.get();
  tagToEdit.pictures = tagToEdit.pictures.length;

  return tagToEdit;
}));

return tags;
}
```

I'm sure that that there should be more optimized and better way to do this, but I don't find it. If You know such way, it would be wonderful if you share it with me.

The output of my method:

```
[
 {
    "id": 1,
    "text": "barbarian",
    "pictures": 2
 },
 {
    "id": 4,
    "text": "bear",
    "pictures": 1
 }
]
```

Comment: Are you aware that `findOne` returns only furst random record  and that's not a guarantee that you don't have other records that satisfy your `where` condition? If you absolutely sure you will always have only one record then you can revert this query and indicate `pictures` model as  amian one and call `count` instead of `findOne`

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I already change it on findAll in my code.